# The に in ように... Is it consistent?

Tags: grammar, particles

Is the に particle in ように consistent in all its uses?

For example...
1/
明日は晴れるように   or
覚えるようにします
I understand the に here to be a target particle for what you are wishing for or trying to achieve.

2/
先生のように教える
Here it seems like it is more like it is making よう into an adverbial form.

Is there an interpretation that encompasses both uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are {noun+の or verbal phrase X}ように{verb Y
}, ie to do Y in a way of X, do Y like or similar to X.

Most literally you could interpret all these sentences in such a way:

I (shall) act such that [in a way that] I remember

[I am wishing] In a way that the weather be clear tomorrow.

To teach in a way a teacher teaches.

The nuances follow quite intuitively.

"in a way such that it is nice tomorrow" starts to make sense once we add the implicit "I/We wish or hope in such a way" or "please act in such a way, {some deity}!".

ようにする, from its literal meaning, has become one standard expression for your goals.

Generalization (extended sense) and concretisation (restricting to one sense), as well as.metaphors are common in language, and I think it's not too hard to see what all these three sentences have got in common.

Comment: Perfect!!!!
I had a hunch that it wasn't a target particle in the first example but so many people tell me it is... 

You explained it really well thankyou!